# How can i download the spike simulator for RISC-V in ubuntu?

Tags: riscv

I am new to RISC-V and i need the spike simulator for performance analysis of my c code. But i am not sure how to download the simulator on ubuntu.
Help will be much appreciated!!
Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get it via run next command in console:
`git clone git@github.com:riscv/riscv-isa-sim.git`, when you stay in desired dir.

How to build it please read on page of repository:
`https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim`

Also before you start i can advice you to read these documents:

- Volume I: User-Level ISA,
- Volume II: Privileged Architecture

Here: https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual

All you need to start you can find here:

- `https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tools` - programming tools.
- `https://github.com/ucb-bar/chipyard` - verilog code generators and simulators.